# File Open Dialog Box on Restart

Tags: windows-7

Recently I've been seeing this dialog box pop up whenever I restart my computer and log in.

[image]

It wants to open a file named after me, it appears to be one located in my C:\Users folder. Why would Windows suddenly want to open this file on login?

Comment: [autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) will tell you what is trying to open it.

Comment: @DavidPostill you can make this an answer, I found it! Turns out Discord wants to open that file for some reason.

Comment: Answer added :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why would Windows suddenly want to open this file on login?

[`autoruns`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) from [Windows Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) will tell you what is trying to open it:

> This utility, which has the most comprehensive knowledge of auto-starting locations of any startup monitor, shows you what programs are configured to run during system bootup or login, and when you start various built-in Windows applications like Internet Explorer, Explorer and media players.
>
> These programs and drivers include ones in your startup folder, Run, RunOnce, and other Registry keys.
>
> Autoruns reports Explorer shell extensions, toolbars, browser helper objects, Winlogon notifications, auto-start services, and much more.
> Autoruns goes way beyond other autostart utilities.
>
> [image]

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Windows Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) in any way, I am just an end user of their software.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have an unassociated file type launching on login.

Given that your computer wants to open something called "Jeff" - take a look at msconfig and see if any entried have a location or command mentioning the name "Jeff".

To do this go to start > run > "msconfig.exe" > OK.

Go to the startup tab and look for the entry that is likely to be causing this.

Untick its corresponding box and then click Apply/OK before restarting your computer.
[image]

Other places to check are:

The All Users Startup Folder: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`  (bear in mind that AppData is hidden so you will need to unhide it in folder optiosn first)

Your startup Folder: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

If you find the eentry you are looking for - simply delete it (or move it to your desktop as a way of backing it up so that you can move it back again)

The following list of registry keys may also have an entry that you are looking for:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Userinit]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows]
```

You can browse the registry by going to Start > Run > "Regedit" > OK

you can delete entries from these registry keys (folders), but remember to backup the key first by right clicking it and selecting export:

[image]

If you do something wrong, you can then simply double click the exported file and import it back into your registry.

Comment: David Postill's recommendation of Autoruns found a reg key from Discord that asked to open the file each time. I figured it wasn't suspicious, as Jeff is my name, but thank you nonetheless! You were right about a registry key. :)